# Adding new elements in JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, typescript, object

I'm trying to add a new element inside of my JSON, but I'm not getting this done right.

I'd already tried with a lot of ways and not sure What is going on.

**INPUT JSON**

```
{
 "UnitID":"1148",
 "UNIT":"202B",
 "Speed":"29.0",
 "SpeedMeasureValue":"MPH",
 "Direction":"212",
 "LatitudeY":"42.0474150666667000",
 "LongitudeX":"-88.2750256000000000",
 "TimeStamp":"2019-04-25 15:19:45.0300000",
 "Status":"Enroute","StatusID":"13",
 "CallID":"841809",
 "ORI":"IL0450600"
}
```

**EXPECTED JSON OUTPUT AFTER CONCATENATION**

```
{
"UnitID":"1148",
"UNIT":"202B",
"Speed":"29.0",
"SpeedMeasureValue":"MPH",
"Direction":"212",
"LatitudeY":"42.0474150666667000",
"LongitudeX":"-88.2750256000000000",
"TimeStamp":"2019-04-25 15:19:45.0300000",
"Status":"Enroute","StatusID":"13",
"CallID":"841809","ORI":"IL0450600", 
"association": [
     {
       "event": "123",
       "label": "", 
       "relation": "321"}
       ]
}
```

**Code** - Consider `objectToJson` as an array of input JSON and `obj` the input json mentioned before

```
objectToJson.forEach((obj: any) => {
const association: any = `"association": [{"event": 123, "label": "", "relation": "321"}]`;
const concatenatedObject: object = Object.assign(obj, association);
const concatEventsJson: any = JSON.stringify(concatenatedObject);
console.log(concatEventsJson);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `association` property to the object - you'll need to make `association` a variable (and not a string) though:

```
const association: any = [{"event": 123, "label": "", "relation": "321"}];
const concatenatedObject: object = { ...obj, association };
```

Demonstration:

```js
const objectToJson = [{"UnitID":"1148","UNIT":"202B","Speed":"29.0","SpeedMeasureValue":"MPH","Direction":"212","LatitudeY":"42.0474150666667000","LongitudeX":"-88.2750256000000000","TimeStamp":"2019-04-25 15:19:45.0300000","Status":"Enroute","StatusID":"13","CallID":"841809","ORI":"IL0450600"}];

objectToJson.forEach((obj) => {
  const association = [{"event": 123, "label": "", "relation": "321"}];
  const concatenatedObject = { ...obj, association };
  console.log(concatenatedObject);
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: Thanks for answer.  I use your code and it add the element, but looks how it add : "association":"[{\"event\": 123, \"label\": \"\", \"relation\": \"321\"}]"}... not a valid JSON